# Marker icon displays both the traditional icon and custom icon after setting icon in marker constructor

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map on a view which displays some markers and with info boxes.
Everything works fine, but when I set the icon property of the map to a unique image, the marker shows both images with my unique icon overlaying the default google pin.
This is what it currently looks like:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idgvt.jpg

I have tried numerous definitions on the map constructor but the result has been the same.

```
var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/rangerstation.png';

//Add markers to view
function addMarker(x, y, ward, community, lganame, projecttype) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
            map: map,
            title: ward
        });

    marker.setIcon(image);

    addInfoWindowToMarker(marker, ward, community, lganame, projecttype);
}
```

I would like the icon being displayed to be just the one I specify and completely ignore the default Google Maps marker.

Comment: Can you please post your full code or a jsfiddle? Your custom marker works without problem on my end; I only see your image, not Google's default marker icon.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing my marker definition as such.
Note I also scaled the size down or better presentation.

```
        function addMarker(x, y, ward, community, lganame, projecttype) {
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: ward,
                //icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/rangerstation.png',
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/rangerstation.png',
                null, /* size is determined at runtime */
                null, /* origin is 0,0 */
                null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
                new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
              )
            });
            //Call info windows and bounce event listener so the marker animates when it is clicked
            addInfoWindowToMarker(marker, ward, community, lganame, projecttype);
        }

It works just fine now.
```